# how array groups by in java script

Tags: javascript, json

hi i am newbie to the java script i am using knex ORM to interact with the data base and i am getting fallowing flat json as a resulted rows and i need to get the result in actual format which i have mentioned in the expected result. i have tried some code but none the code gives me expected result. i have mention my prototype code which i tried and also the result of the  code,which not in the format which i want how can i get the actual result which i mentioned in the EXPECTED result section ,how can i achieve same using lodash or ES6 higher order function.

```
var data= [
    {order_id: 1,kot_id: 10,price: 20,quantity: 2},
    {order_id: 1,kot_id: 10,price: 100,quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1,kot_id: 10,price: 150,quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1,kot_id: 11,price: 55,quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1,kot_id: 11,price: 250,quantity: 3},
]



let objects = {}
let arr = []
result = data.forEach((item,index) => {
    if(!objects.order_id) {
        objects = {order_id: item.order_id,list: []}
        arr.push(objects)
    }
    if(!objects.kot_id) {
         objects.list.push({kot_id: item.kot_id,kot_list: []})

    }
    objects.list[index].kot_list.push({price: item.price,quantity: item.quantity})

})
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr,null,2))

RESULT OF THE ABOVE CODE
[

  {
    "order_id": 1,
    "list": [
      {
        "kot_id": 10,
        "kot_list": [
          {
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "kot_id": 10,
        "kot_list": [
          {
            "price": 100,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "kot_id": 10,
        "kot_list": [
          {
            "price": 150,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "kot_id": 11,
        "kot_list": [
          {
            "price": 55,
            "quantity": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "kot_id": 11,
        "kot_list": [
          {
            "price": 250,
            "quantity": 3
          },

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

EXPECTED RESULT

result = [
    {
        order_id: 1,
        list: [
            {
                kot_id: 10,
                kot_list : [
                    { price: 200,quantity: 2 },
                    {price: 100,quantity: 1},
                    {price: 150,quantity: 1}
                ]
            },
            {
                kot_id: 11,
                kot_list: [
                    {price: 55,quantity: 1},
                    {price: 250,quantity: 3}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: how can i obtain above result using lodash

Answer (score 1):

[lodash](https://lodash.com/) utilities like [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#groupBy) and [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) should do the work.

Lodash example:

```js
const data = [
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 20, quantity: 2},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 100, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 150, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 11, price: 55, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 11, price: 250, quantity: 3},

    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 10, price: 150, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 11, price: 55, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 11, price: 250, quantity: 3},
]


const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('order_id')
  .mapValues((values, key) => {
    return _(values)
      .groupBy('kot_id')
      .map((list, id) => ({
        kot_id: id,
        kot_list: _.map(list, i => _.pick(i, ['price', 'quantity']))
      }))
      .value();
  })
  .map((list, order_id) => ({order_id, list}))
  .value();


console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can simply use ES6 utilities to achieve the same result:

Plain ES6 example:

```js
const data = [
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 20, quantity: 2},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 100, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 10, price: 150, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 11, price: 55, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 1, kot_id: 11, price: 250, quantity: 3},

    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 10, price: 150, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 11, price: 55, quantity: 1},
    {order_id: 2, kot_id: 11, price: 250, quantity: 3},
]


const orderIds = [...new Set(data.map(i => i.order_id))];
const kotIds = [... new Set(data.map(i => i.kot_id))];

const result = orderIds.map(order_id => {
  return {
    order_id,
    list: kotIds
      .map(kot_id => {
        return {
          kot_id,
          kot_list: data
            .filter(i => i.order_id === order_id && i.kot_id === kot_id)
            .map(i => ({price: i.price, quantity: i.quantity}))
        }
      })
  };
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: how can we achieve same in es6 higher order function

Comment: yes, but the solution will have more lines of code)

Comment: I've added plain ES6 sample